# I am getting MemoryError in Jupyter notebook while running simple commands like pd.unique on a dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am encountering **MemoryError** in Jupyter Python notebook while running command - pd.unique on a dataframe column.

I encountered this error earlier as well while using pd.read_csv while importing a csv file while was ~3GB size.
However, on re-installing python this worked fine and pd.read_csv worked fine.

Comment: Maybe you ran out of memory?

Comment: The sys is 8GB RAM , 64bit OS and the drive is 43GB free of 104 GB. Any inputs please suggest?